# Binding constantly updated string to a Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

I can't bind my `String` to a textbox.
I am sure this is an easy questions, i did google it a lot, still it wont work for me. I have tried several solutions i found online with no success.

I have a string (inputread) which gets its value constantly updated in a thread

```
_inputread = plc.input[1];
```

how do i bind this string to a textbox which gets craeted when the program is started (newtextbox)?

```
private string _inputread;
public string inputread
{
    get { return _inputread; }
    set
    {
        _inputread = plc.InputImage[1].ToString();
        OnPropertyChanged("inputread");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

later on:

```
 Binding bind = new Binding(inputread);
 bind.Source = inputread;
 newtextbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
```

Thank you!

Comment: When the value change just do `textbox.Text = yourvalue` ?

Comment: How do i do that? When the value is red into _inputread i should call an event? and that even should redo the textbox.text= yourvalue ?

Comment: You code is a bit confusing. You are only using the backingfield `_inputread`. Your property is never used, so it will never fire `OnPropertyChanged`

Comment: *"its value constantly updated in a thread"* - sounds like you need to rise notification each time you set new value. Of course this notification has to be invoked in UI thread. Saying simple do `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(inputread)));` everytime when you change `plc.InputImage`.

Comment: I might not understand the concept behind binding. If i bind the textbox to the string _inputread shouldn't the textbox just automatically update it any time the _inputread is updated?

Comment: Nope, it won't as it is now (you hide collection behind property which simply return string). For this to work you have to bind to it directly and it has to provide notification (e.g. it should be `ObservableCollection<>`).

Comment: binding will not do any automated update for you, you have to call update text box from your working thread to UI thread each time

Comment: I am sorry it wont work with Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_inputread))); added to the thread which updates inputread's value, what/how else should I try?
 `void threadFunc()
        {
            try
            {
                while (threadRunning)
                {
                    plc.Read();
                    _inputread = plc.InputImage[1].ToString();
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(inputread)));
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
            }
        }`

Comment: Describe *"it wont work"*, what doesn't work? Perhaps you simply miss `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke ...` or what?

Comment: So i am using the same code as in the question, only adding the `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(inputread))); ` to the thread updating the value, when i run the program the textbox is simply empty. Did i understand you well and did what you meant?

Comment: See my answer for a fixed property. For your property to work you have to do something like `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => InputImage = "doesn'tmatterwhat"));` - this way you will rise notification properly. Using backend field, which is updated in the setter is a weird idea.

Answer (score 1):

You seems overestimate the power of binding. This part

```
string _inputRead;
public string InputRead // fixing naming
{
    get { return _inputRead; }
    set
    {
        _inputRead = plc.InputImage[1].ToString();
        OnPropertyChanged("inputread");
    }
}
```

will only rise notification when you change `InputRead` directly, e.g. by setting it:

```
InputRead = "someNewValue";
```

Probably you want a simple getter-only property instead

```
public string InputRead => plc.InputImage[1].ToString();
```

but you have to rise notification every time when `plc.InputImage` is changed

```
// assuming it's another thread, call this when you want view to update the value
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputRead)));
```

Talking about MVVM, your model have to rise notification when `plc.InputImage` is changed, e.g. event `InputImageChanged`. ViewModel subscribe to it and in event handler calls above line.

---

Here is a complete solution:

```
public string InputRead => plc.InputImage[1].ToString();

void ThreadFunc()
{
    while (threadRunning)
    {
        plc.Read();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputRead)));
    }
}
```

Comment: had to comment in answer, i cant edit this small space.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string inputread => plc.InputImage[1].ToString();

    void threadFunc()
    {
        try
        {
            while (threadRunning)
            {
                plc.Read();
                inputread = plc.InputImage[1].ToString();
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(inputread)));
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
        }
    }
```

Like this? I am sorry if i am wasting your time, I'm new to c# and wpf.
2 errors:
error1 :"inputread: Property or indexer 'MainWindow.inputread' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"
error 2:"nameof(inputread) Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs'

Comment: Remove `inputread = plc......` line completely. Getter-only property already does that (retrieves the value). All you need is to tell view "value was changed, please update" (this is done by calling `OnPropertyChanged`), then view get value of property (which returns updated value of `InputImage`). For the future - consider to ask separate question next time.

Comment: See edit to my answer.

Comment: second error is still present saying "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs' " on "nameof(InputRead)"  thank you for all your help

Comment: Check your `OnPropertyChanged` method. I don't know why it needs something like this. It suppose to be a string (looking at the method you have provided in the question).

Comment: no errors this time but the textbox is still empty. Is there no simple way to keep a textbox updated, is binding the best way? I really don't want to bother you much more, could you tell me what to google to find some answers/solutions?

Comment: Btw, you can add clarification to question itself (for the future). Right now you better ask another question (too many things to ask to clarify, I am not able to answer directly in just one comment, sorry). Make sure to include complete source and explain what you are trying to achieve and what doesn't work. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).